# Speaking with an ISpVoice from a ISpTTSEngine

Tags: visual-c++, com, text-to-speech, sapi

I'm implementing an ISpTTSEngine for the Microsoft Speech API (SAPI). I'd like for
this voice to annunciate just like a typical TTS voice. Rather than write my
own speech synthesizer, I'd like to delegate to a built-in ISpVoice.

I've written enough code to hear text vocalized, but it has a major deficiency
that I haven't been able to explain: the speech does not begin until after my
implementation of `ISpTTSEngine:Speak` has returned. For the duration of the
audible output, my implementation of `ISpTTSEngine:Speak` is not invoked, even
when the software using the TTS voice is sending requests.

(For context: my goal for this project is to programmatically observe the speech data that other pieces
of software are attempting to vocalize. That part appears to be working as
intended.)

[The full source is available
here.](https://github.com/bocoup/at-automation-experiment/tree/70d01dd522808f0f5aaa6f87c247ecd690c05fa8) I'll try to
summarize with the most relevant parts.

[My implementation of `ISpTTSEngine` has a private member named
`m_cpVoice`](https://github.com/bocoup/at-automation-experiment/blob/70d01dd522808f0f5aaa6f87c247ecd690c05fa8/automationttsengine/ttsengobj.h#L118):

```cpp
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CTTSEngObj :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CTTSEngObj, &CLSID_SampleTTSEngine>,
    public ISpTTSEngine,
    public ISpObjectWithToken
{
  // ...
  private:
    CComPtr<ISpVoice> m_cpVoice;
```

And [it is initialized in the `FinalConstruct`
method](https://github.com/bocoup/at-automation-experiment/blob/70d01dd522808f0f5aaa6f87c247ecd690c05fa8/automationttsengine/ttsengobj.cpp#L110):

```cpp
HRESULT CTTSEngObj::FinalConstruct()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // ...

    hr = m_cpVoice.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice);
```

My implementation of `ISpTTSEngine:Speak` [iterates over the text fragments it
receives](https://github.com/bocoup/at-automation-experiment/blob/70d01dd522808f0f5aaa6f87c247ecd690c05fa8/automationttsengine/ttsengobj.cpp#L218)
and [passes the text data to the `ISpVoice::Speak`
method](https://github.com/bocoup/at-automation-experiment/blob/70d01dd522808f0f5aaa6f87c247ecd690c05fa8/automationttsengine/ttsengobj.cpp#L226):

```cpp
STDMETHODIMP CTTSEngObj::Speak(DWORD dwSpeakFlags,
    REFGUID rguidFormatId,
    const WAVEFORMATEX* pWaveFormatEx,
    const SPVTEXTFRAG* pTextFragList,
    ISpTTSEngineSite* pOutputSite)
{
    // ...

    for (const SPVTEXTFRAG* textFrag = pTextFragList; textFrag != NULL; textFrag = textFrag->pNext)
    {

        // ...

        const std::wstring& text = textFrag->pTextStart;
        hr = m_cpVoice->Speak(text.substr(0, textFrag->ulTextLen).c_str(), dwSpeakFlags | SPF_ASYNC | SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK, 0);
```

As mentioned above, no audio is emitted until after `ISpTTSEngine:Speak`
returns. An arbitrary sleep statement demonstrates this most clearly. Polling
the ISpVoice's `SpeakCompleteEvent` handle inevitably times out. Removing the
`SPF_ASYNC` flag from the invocation of `ISpVoice::Speak` causes the caller to
crash.

Can anyone explain this behavior? Or suggest a change that would allow me to
observe subsequent speech requests?

Answer (score 1):

SAPI isn't expecting to be entered recursively.   Consider using a different TTS engine (e.g., the WinRT [System.Media.SpeechSynthesis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis?view=winrt-22000#:%7E:text=Classes%20%20%20Speech%20Synthesis%20Stream%20%20,info%20about%20an%20installed%20speech%20%20...%20) APIs) to do the actual synthesis.   The text fragments won't have any embedded markup, so that won't be a big deal.

Comment: I'm trying to better understand the platform so I can recognize constraints like this on my own. Would you recommend a closer reading of Microsoft's "[TTS Engine Vendor Porting Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee431802(v=vs.85))"? Is there some other documentation that could help?

Answer (score 0):

As per document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee431810(v=vs.85)

> If you want to speak asynchronously, change the speak flag to SPF_ASYNC and call ISpVoice::WaitUntilDone() after the ISpVoice::Speak() waiting for the completion of the speak process.